# Get types in Python expression using MyPy as library

Tags: python, type-inference, mypy

I have some Python source code, and want to find out the type of a variable. For example given the string

```
"""
greeting = "Hello"
"""
```

I want to have `get_type('greeting') == str`. Or a more complex example:

```
"""
def test(input: str):
    output = len(input)
    return str
"""
```

In pseudocode, I want to be able to do something like:

```
>>> m = parse_module()
>>> m.functions['test'].locals['output'].get_type()
int
```

It seems this should be possible with type annotations and MyPy in Python 3, but I can't figure out how. IDEs like VS code have become very good at guessing the types in python code, that is why I'm guessing there must be an exposed way to do this.

There seems to be a module [typed-ast](https://github.com/python/typed_ast), which is also used by MyPy, that gets me part of the way there. However, this does no type inference or propagation, it just gives me the explicit annotations as far as I understand. MyPy as an api, but it only lets you run the checker, and returns the same error messages as the command line tool. I am looking for a way to "reach into" MyPy, and get some of the inferred information out - or some alternative solution I haven't thought of.

Comment: You might be able to use the `inspect` module. It is a Python introspection helper.

Comment: Im confused can you not just use the `type()` function?

Comment: I have the code as a string, and I don't want to execute it. I want to get the types of variables contained in the source code.

Answer (score 4):

Mypy currently has an extremely primitive, bare-bones API, which you can find "documented" within the source code here: https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/master/mypy/api.py. To use it, you essentially need to write your string to a temporary file which you later clean up.

You can perhaps combine this with the `reveal_type(...)` special directive (and perhaps even the [hidden `--shadow-file`](https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/master/mypy/main.py#L325) option) to typecheck your string.

The other alternative is to reverse engineer and re-implement pieces of [mypy's main.py](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3553), essentially hijacking their internal API. I don't really think this will be hard, just somewhat ugly and fragile.

(Note that mypy can theoretically support typechecking arbitrary strings, and the core devs aren't opposed to extending the API for mypy in principle -- it's just that mypy is still under active development which means implementing an API has been very low priority for a while now. And since mypy is still actively being worked on/extended, the devs are somewhat reluctant to commit to implementing a more complex API that they'll subsequently have to support. You can find more context and details regarding the current state of the API in mypy's issue tracker.)